# I am stuck in an if else statement trying to compare two string values stored in "char" variables

Tags: arrays, c, string, if-statement

I am a beginner C programmer so my question may sound vague but please bear it with me ;).
So I was trying to create a program in which the user enters the subject he has passed in (There are three options : Math, Physics or both) and based on the input the computer prints the prize money on the screen.
But when I execute the program it just exits after the first IF STATEMENT, for example if I enter the option BOTH or PHYSICS, The output still shows $5 prize which should be only shown when math is given as the input. Can you guys kindly guide me what mistake I am making?
Thanks in advance,
Bilal Ahmed.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])

{
char Math,Physics,Both,subject;
printf("Please enter the name of the subjects you have passed in...\nOptionA)Math\nOptionB)Physics\nOptionC)Both\n");

scanf("%s", & subject);
if (subject= Math)
{
printf("you will receive $5\n");
}
else if (subject= Physics)
{
printf("you will receive $10\n");
}
else if (subject= Both)
{
printf("you will receive $15\n");
}
return 0
}
```

Comment: `=` is not `==`

Comment: C doesn't have a string class and `char` is not that (non-existing) string class. From there on, please study the chapters regarding arrays and strings in your C programming book.

Comment: Additionally, the = vs == bug, known since the 1970s, is no doubt addressed by that same book. A good book will tell you to enable and read compiler warnings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`char` data type is to store a single character not a string. So as to take input a string you need a character array.  You need to understand the difference between handling a single character and a string in C.

```
char Math,Physics,Both,subject;     // subject needs to be a character array 
printf("Please enter the name of the subjects you have passed in...\nOptionA)Math\nOptionB)Physics\nOptionC)Both\n");

scanf("%s", & subject);   // Also %s doesn't require & operator with character array.
//for character we use %c
```

So you need to declare `subject` as `char subject[15]`. Leaving space for null terminator.

Second to compare strings you need to use `strcmp` in C. So an example of comparisons is :-

```
if(strcmp(subject, "Math") == 0){
    //stuff
}
...
```

Answer (score 2):

The statement of

```
(subject= Math)
```

assigns the value of `Math` to `subject` and evaluates to it. If it's truey, then it will enter that branch of the `if`. You've meant

```
(subject== Math)
```

to only compare without assignment, and also don't forget to initialize your variables. Happy coding!